# Angular Dynamic form observable property binding

Tags: forms, angular, ngrx

I have a problem with some dynamically generated forms and passing values to them. I feel like someone must have solved this, or I’m missing something obvious, but  I can't find any mention of it.

So for example, I have three components, a parent, a child, and then a child of that child. For names, I’ll go with, formComponent, questionComponent, textBoxComponent. Both of the children are using changeDetection.OnPush.

So form component passes some values down to questionComponent through the inputs, and some are using the async pipe to subscribe to their respective values in the store.

QuestionComponent dynamically creates different components, then places them on the page if they match (so many types of components, but each questionComponent only handles on one component.

some code:

```
@Input() normalValue
@Input() asyncPipedValue
@ViewChild('questionRef', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public questionRef: any;
private textBoxComponent: ComponentFactory<TextBoxComponent>;

ngOnInit() {
let component = 
this.questionRef.createComponent(this.checkboxComponent);
component.instance.normalValue = this.normalValue;
component.instance. asyncPipedValue = this. asyncPipedValue;
}
```

This works fine for all instances of normalValues, but not for asyncValues. I can confirm in questionComponent’s ngOnChanges that the value is being updated, but that value is not passed to textBoxComponent.

What I basically need is the async pipe, but not for templates. I’ve tried multiple solutions to different ways to pass asyncValues, I’ve tried detecting when asyncPipeValue changes, and triggering changeDetectionRef.markForChanges() on the textBoxComponent, but that only works when I change the changeDetectionStrategy to normal, which kinda defeats the performance gains I get from using ngrx.

This seems like too big of an oversight to not already have a solution, so I’m assuming it’s just me not thinking of something. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide plunker?

Comment: Have you looked into BehaviorSubject? You can have a service run the logic and/or modify your asyncValue as the BehaviorSubject, and have each component subscribe to an Observable of that BehaviorSubject.

Comment: ^ Why do we need `BehaviorSubject` when using ngrx , we can just store in 'store' right  ?

Comment: @Austin you can do most of the stuff without having components interact each other , are you fine with that or particular about them in communication

Comment: @Austin, plunker is needed to show your case.

Comment: @e-cloud I'll try to get a plunker, there's just alot to setup. I think I may have a solution with manually resetting the instance value each time the parent ngOnChanges fires.

Comment: you can start with this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/bcxczZ2Tzyee70TtLrIJ

Comment: You can try to make you input not as value but as observable. Something like  @Input() asyncPipedValue: Observable<any>;

Comment: From what I recall if you use onPushChangeDetection triggers re-rendering of components ,not only if input property changes, but also if an output event is emitted, or an observable to which the template has subscribed to using the async pipe is changed. it's best to have your component properties all use Observables and have subcomponents use observables that are derived from a parent observable via map and in the templates render with  observable variable that gets passed thru | async pipe

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova I've tried that, but I don't want to just pass an unsubscribed observable as an input to the child

Comment: @JGFMK That would normally be what I'd do, but these are dynamic components, thus there is no async pipe to use.

Comment: Clutching at straws a bit here.. Nothing to do with compiler is it...  https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler#compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync  https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: @JGFMK nice article, it seems to mention the problem, but it stops short of attacking (which all articles seem to). I have a somewhat solution below, but it needs some more work to get full functionality, because I need to still be able to use ngOnChanges on the textBoxComponent

Comment: can you add some more code? how do the templates of your components look? Passing values through the component hierarchy shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar, whereby I have forms populated from data coming from my Ngrx Store. My forms aren't dynamic so I'm not 100% sure if this will also work for you.

Define your input with just a setter, then call patchValue(), or setValue() on your form/ form control. Your root component stays the same, passing the data into your next component with the async pipe.

```
@Input() set asyncPipedValue(data) {
  if (data) {
    this.textBoxComponent.patchValue(data);
  }
}
```

patchValue() is on the AbstractControl class. If you don't have access to that from your question component, your TextBoxComponent could expose a similar method, that can be called from your QuestionComponent, with the implementation performing the update of the control.

One thing to watch out for though, if you're also subscribing to valueChanges on your form/control, you may want to set the second parameter so the valueChanges event doesn't fire immediately.

```
this.textBoxComponent.patchValue(data, { emitEvent: false });
```

or

```
this.textBoxComponent.setValue(...same as above);
```

Then in your TextBoxComponent

```
this.myTextBox.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(a couple of seconds maybe)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(changes => {
    this.store.dispatch(changes);
  })
  .subscribe();
```

This approach is working pretty well, and removes the need to have save/update buttons everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts on the question, taking into account limited code snippet.

First, provided example doesn't seem to have anything to do with `ngrx`. In this case, it is expected that `ngOnInit` runs only once and at that time `this.asyncPipedValue` value is `undefined`. Consequently, if  `changeDetection` of `this.checkboxComponent` is `ChangeDetection.OnPush` the value won't get updated. I recommend reading [one excellent article](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/03/angular-tuning-change-detection/) about change detection and passing async inputs. That article also contains other not less great resources on change detection. In addition, it seems that the same inputs are passed twice through the component tree which is not a good solution from my point of view.

Second, another approach would be to use `ngrx` and then you don't need to pass any async inputs at all. Especially, this way is good if two components do not have the parent-child relationship in the component tree. In this case, one component dispatches action to put data to Store and another component subscribes to that data from Store.

```
export class DataDispatcherCmp {

    constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {
    }

    onNewData(data: SomeData) {
        this.store.dispatch(new SetNewDataAction(data));
    }
}

export class DataConsumerCmp implements OnInit {

    newData$: Observable<SomeData>;

    constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.newData$ = this.store.select('someData');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps or gives some clues at least.

Comment: So the same input is not passed twice, it's passed from a parent to a child, which then has to be passed to another child. The 1st child's inputs are subscribed with async pipe, so they will change over time (in fact it's the child of the 1st child that emits an action and changes store, which has new data passed).

Comment: Ok, not sure what is going on there. Need to see all 3 components involved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out a solution (with some help from the gitter.com/angular channel).

Since the values are coming in to the questionComponent can change, and trigger it's ngOnChanges to fire, whenever there is an event in ngOnChanges, it needs to parse through the event, and bind and changes to the dynamic child component.

```
ngOnChanges(event) {
if (this.component) {
  _.forEach(event, (value, key) => {
    if (value && value.currentValue) {
      this.component.instance[key] = value.currentValue;
    }
  });
 }
}
```

This is all in questionComponent, it resets the components instance variables if they have changed. The biggest problem with this so far, is that the child's ngOnChanges doesn't fire, so this isn't a full solution. I'll continue to dig into it.

Comment: Does your TextBoxComponent expose any angular AbstractControl component? Or does it extend AbstractControl?

Comment: @MattSugden It doesn't extend an abstractControl, I pass down a formControl instance that gets bound to [formControl] on the template